# What does "missing lifetime specifier" mean when storing a &str in a structure?

Tags: rust

I am trying to code an Excel-like data structure:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct Excel {
    columns: HashMap<&str, Vec<f64>>,
}

fn main() {}
```

but I am getting an error:

```
error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
 --> src/main.rs:4:22
  |
4 |     columns: HashMap<&str, Vec<f64>>,
  |                      ^ expected lifetime parameter
```

Can someone help me understand what's going on?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

"Missing lifetime specifier" means that in the struct definition, you haven't told it how long the reference to the string slice is allowed to stay around. In order for your code to be safe, it has to stick around for at least as long as the struct.

You need to define a lifetime parameter on your struct and use it for the string slice.

```
struct Excel<'a> {
    columns: HashMap<&'a str, Vec<f64>>
}
```

This says that string slice (the `HashMap` key) has some lifetime parameterized by the user of the `Excel` struct. Lifetimes are one of the key features of Rust. You can read more about lifetimes in [Rust documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/lifetimes.html).

Usually it's simpler to define a struct that owns the string. Then you can use `String`.

```
struct Excel {
    columns: HashMap<String, Vec<f64>>
}
```

Comment: More fidelity here would be to say that the struct needs a *lifetime parameter* (using generics), so that for each given lifetime `'x` and `&'x str`, it can be stored in corresponding type `Excel<'x>`.  “Same lifetime as the struct” isn't exactly what's happening. A lifetime parameter allows the struct to describe borrows, for example  `fn foo<'a>(&'a self) -> Excel<'a>`  (The Excel struct borrows from self, but the concrete lifetime is filled in by concrete call of that method).

Comment: The String key suggestion is good, too. It's usually what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Reference to the struct field should live as long as the structure itself lives. Because we do not want to have a structure with a reference field which is pointing to an invalid resource. For example

```
struct Person<'a>{
    name:&'a str,
    age:i32,
}
fn main(){
  let first_name="yilmaz";
  let mut person=Person{
    name:&first_name,
    age:32
  };
  {
    let last_name=String::from("bingol");
    // `last_name` does not live long enough
    // borrowed value does not live long enough
    person.name=&last_name;
  }
  // If I remove the print, code will have no issue
  println!("person name is {} and his age is {}",person.name,person.age)
}
```

in `println!` Person struct is still live but `last_name` does not live long enough, its scope is over inside code block and yet we are trying to access it inside the `pirntln!`